# Django password_reset won't start tls authentication to send email

Tags: python, django, email

I have the following set up below:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL__USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = None #'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = None #'password'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
SERVER_EMAIL = 'user@gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
```

in settings.py.  However, when I call password_reset, which handles sending an email in Django, `SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.` is thrown.  Is there an additional step to the `password_reset()` method?  I'm simply passing this to my free smtp.gmail.com server through my Gmail account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a double underscore in the `EMAIL_USE_TLS` setting.

Comment: Wow that was a simple mistake.  I'll add more information on setting up SMTP with Gmail so this question isn't completely useless.

Comment: And for posterity's sake, as of the date this was posted, this method still works in Django.

Answer (score 0):

Additional steps to set up Gmail SMTP:

-Make sure to enable IMAP under Gmail -> Cog icon -> Settings -> Forward and POP/IMAP

-Make sure to let less-secure apps access the account (at your own risk)